# jQuery show next set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle visibility of the following links after I click on the H2 but I keep coming up against a brick wall.

Here is the html and jquery

```
<div class="entry-content cibi">

<h2><strong>Corporate Infrastructure Service Plan</strong></h2>
<p><a href="http://intranet/cibi/files/2014/03/Service-Plan-including-Service-specific-risks-and-all-action-plans-.docx">Service Plan (including Service specific risks and all action plans)</a></p>
<p><a href="http://intranet/cibi/files/2014/03/Scorecard.pdf">Scorecard</a></p>
<p><a href="http://intranet/cibi/files/2014/03/Corporate-Infrastructure-Service-Plan.xls">Corporate Infrastructure Service Plan</a></p>

<h2><strong>Employee Statistics</strong></h2>
<p><a href="http://intranet/cibi/files/2014/03/Absence-Management-Statistics-.xls">Absence Management Statistics</a></p>

</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$( "h2" ).click(function() {    
    $(this).nextuntil("h2").toggle()
    return false;
});

 });
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `nextUntil()` has a capital `U`

Comment: You're looking for [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) or just [next](http://api.jquery.com/next)

Comment: Thanks that was it a capital! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/75qCv/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "h2" ).click(function() {    
$(this).nextUntill('h2').toggle()
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its `nextUntil()` not `nextuntil()`

```
$( "h2" ).click(function() {    
$(this).nextUntil("h2").toggle()
return false;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5UUk/3/)